# Remove project .jars from project explorer view in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, jar, classpath

The list of jars just takes up too much space. Can I collapse it or hide it?

Comment: Guys, the question is talking about "project explorer" not "package explorer".
in Helios, there is no 'Show Referenced Libraries Node' in project explorer.

Comment: Easiest solution: use Windows >> Show View >> Package Explorer instead

Comment: I have the same problem in Eclipse 4.2 and none of the answers below to date work for me. There must be a way.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In the Project Explorer :

- Customize View
- Check `Libraries from external`

[image]
[image]

Or in the Package Explorer :

- Uncheck the 'Show Referenced Libraries Node'
- Add a filter to hide "*.jar" files

Comment: As PeterMa mentioned on the Question itself, this is not correct; it may work for the Package Explorer, but there is no such option in the Project Explorer.

Comment: This also means that if you're trying to build a jar file, you no longer have a JAR-description entry on which to right click and select "Create JAR".

Comment: This is not correct as far as the original question since it is about the project explorer.   See the answer by @Wl.

Answer (score 55):

Another solution would be using the Package Explorer view.

Comment: Windows >> Show View >> Package Explorer

Comment: package explorer is the easiest solution for the problem

Comment: Just saying "use package explorer" is really not an answer to the original question.  The two serve similar but slightly different purposes. It is true that if you only work with java you probably don't notice much difference but if you work with multiple languages you see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265070/what-is-the-difference-between-the-eclipse-package-explorer-and-the-eclipse-proj

Answer (score 37):

In Eclipse3.5, select the filter "libraries from external" in "customize view".

Comment: Project Explorer > [Down Arrow Icon] > Customize View

Comment: This is the correct answer for the project explorer view thank you!

Answer (score 6):

In Eclipse 3.7

- open view menu (arrow down icon in right section of title) of Project Explorer
- select Customize View menu item
- in Available Customization window on Filters tab check Library from external and click OK

Answer (score 5):

In Eclipse3.5

- Go to Configure Build Path. Select the Library Tab
- Remove any library jar files you want to hide
- Use Add External Jar option to add the Jar file back
- select the filter "libraries from external" in "customize view".

Answer (score 2):

Works for eclipse 3 and 4 in the project explorer and package explorer views.

Hey here is how it works:

- Drop down on the ceiling -> Customize View... -> Filters tick "Libraries from external"
- Right click on the project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Remove all jars -> Add EXTERNAL jars -> add all jars

There you go.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that Eclipse 3.4.2 places jars under "Referenced Libraries" node which is collpasable. What version do you use?

Answer (score 1):

Go the library Tab of Java Build Path, Add Variable (add a variable name and library folder location).

Once the variable is added, click on extend, you will see all the jars. Select all of them (or whatever is needed) and click ok. Exit the build path dialog box by clicking ok.

This will remove all the jars from your project view.

Answer (score 1):

Project Explorer > [Down Arrow Icon] > Customize View > Choose the options which you want to exclude to see in the explorer

Comment: No option for *.jar in my Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

**In Eclipse Luna:**

1. On the toolbar for the Project Explorer, click the Menu button **'view menu'** (arrow) to open the drop-down menu of display options.
2. Select *Customize View...*
3. In the dialog box that opens, select the Filters tab and then select the checkboxes for the types of files that you want to hide.

For hiding ***.jar** select ***Libraries from external***.
For more info check: [Eclipse help](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-48b.htm)

Answer (score 0):

On Juno, see the "View menu" button on the left of the Project Explorer minimize button.
Develop the menu and select the "Customize view" option.
In the Filter tab, check the "Libraries from external" option. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

For Eclipse STS,

A quick work around to stop looking at your large list of jar files is to switch to Navigator view instead. For my purposes navigator works the same as project explorer. 
I tried adding a custom filter "*.jar" in project view however custom filters is unavailable in STS. Also Customize View... -> Filters tick "Libraries from external" is only for 3rd party jars, it doesn't work for custom jars in your project.