# Is it possible to group projects in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, project

Is it possible to group projects in Eclipse? Or maybe have a project with sub-projects?

Comment: Hmm, I think there is an ambiguation in your question. What exactly do you mean with "group projects"? What is the final purpose of this?

Comment: I guess, the final purpose would be to reduce clutter that comes with storing unrelated projects in the same workspace. At least it is for me when I was looking this question up.

Comment: Have a look at this http://eclipse.dzone.com/articles/categorise-projects-package It solved my problem.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

Eclipse offers working sets. You can reduce the projects shown in the Package Explorer and other places to whichever projects you defined into the working set. You can also show the union of various sets, and similar gymnastics.

You can define/edit/delete working sets from the little triangle dropdown menu on the Package Explorer and similar directory views.

Comment: One thing to watch out with Working Sets is there no "Other Projects" Working Set in the Project Explorer so its easy to miss new projects that you have failed to categorize. Package Explorer does have this, but its missing other features (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265070/what-is-the-difference-between-the-eclipse-package-explorer-and-the-eclipse-proj). The issue to track/vote having it added to Project Explorer is https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=266030.

Comment: 11 years later "Other Projects" now exists.

Answer (score 11):

Using `Working Sets`, you can add and organize them as shown in the picture :

[image]

As you can see my Java projects are in Working sets like `Sem1` and `TPs`.

When you create an all new Project, just add the project to your working set, like this :

[image]

Comment: this was actually very helpful to me. I just needed to click "Top Level Elements" and select "Working Sets". I simply didn't have the view I configured showing. Thanks!!

Comment: Do you know if that option (Top Level Elements -> Working Sets) is available for the PROJECT Explorer view? I don't seem to be able to make it work like in the Package Explorer :(

Answer (score 8):

You have two options, as far as I know:

1. use the already suggested Working Set option: you can create custom groups, use them to focus on a particular area of a project, activate them through Mylin; a really powerful tool indeed
2. use the basic concept of workspace which allows you to work on many projects and relate them (via the Build path "Projects" tab, and "Java EE Module Dependencies") so that when you need resources from other projects or you need to deploy them along with your main web application Eclipse will do that for you

Answer (score 7):

What about eclipse working sets? You define a working set and then add some projects to it. Later you could select a working set and only the projects you selected earlier are shown in project explorer.
Simpl grouping to reduce clutter.

http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/cworkset.htm

Answer (score 0):

Since Eclipse Mars M5, you can see a hierarchical view of nested projects in the Project Explorer view. In the view menu, click "Projects Layout > Hierarchical". https://www.eclipse.org/mars/noteworthy/#_nested_hierarchical_view_of_projects

Answer (score 0):

Working sets are great, but they don't work if the projects in one working set has the same name as in another, and such occurs in some TI C2000 chip examples that are in different directories.