# Java/C++ Project management in Eclipse?

Tags: java, c++, eclipse

I use both Java (J2SE) and C++ (use CDT plugin) in Eclipse. So I want manage separate Java projects and C++ projects. I switch C++ perspective, I see a fast view is called "C/C++ Projects", but it contain all my Java projects !

So how can I do to manage separate Java and C++ projects ? Thanks !

Answer (score 5):

Use Eclipse's [Working Sets](http://live.eclipse.org/node/489). You can configure Working Sets to only show for particular perspectives, which should accomplish your goals.

Additional resources on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173439/is-it-possible-to-group-projects-in-eclipse) and in the [Eclipse documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/cworkset.htm).

Answer (score 2):

I use separate workspace for each programming language. That works too.