# Organize Eclipse Projects

Tags: eclipse, import, projects

How do I organize my projects like this? Different projects under one Java Project or something on Eclipse

Thanks!

[image: Different projects under Stable Projects]

Comment: Try 'Working sets' in eclipse. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173439/is-it-possible-to-group-projects-in-eclipse