# Could anyone explain the exact difference among project explorer, package explorer and navigator in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, project, package, navigator

What are the exact differences between project explorer, package explorer and navigator in eclipse?

I am so confused of using the three. Because all seem to fit the same purpose. I don't know, what the exact difference is. Could anyone explain this to me and suggest which one is better for checking out?

Answer (score 21):

From the [Eclipse Documentation about the Common Navigator Framework](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fcnf.htm):

> There are currently 3 major navigators in the Eclipse IDE.
>
> 1. **Project Explorer** - This is an instance of the `CommonNavigator` that is provided by the `org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources` plugin. It provides a **view of the workspace** and has a **large number of NCEs** contributed for resources, Java, C, Web Tools, Data Tools, PHP, etc.
> 2. **Package Explorer** - Provided by the Java Development Tools (JDT) UI project, this provides a **view of Java classes for the workspace**. Generally speaking, the presentation of the Package Explorer and Project Explorer for Java objects is substantially similar. The JDT is not used for projects beyond Java.
> 3. **Navigator** - This view is an implementation of the now deprecated (as of 3.5) `org.eclipse.ui.views.navigator.ResourceNavigator` class provided in the `org.eclipse.ui.ide` plugin. It **shows only the workspace resources** and **does not support extensibility to show other content**. In a future release, the Navigator view will be provided by an implementation of the CommonNavigator.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So stick to 'Project Explorer' - in my testings it overlay more information on the icons such as file warnings and errors.

Answer (score 1):

Also see [What is the difference between the Eclipse Package Explorer and the Eclipse Project Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265070/what-is-the-difference-between-the-eclipse-package-explorer-and-the-eclipse-proj) for specific differences between Project Explorer and Package Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Main visual difference for users is that Package Expplorer shows **multiple** src/main folders, multiple src/test folders, etc etc. This takes a lot of screen space and makes you search for the "right" folder

The navigator always shows only 1 src/main folder.