# Show a file in Eclipse in Windows explorer

Tags: java, eclipse

I found no easy way to show a file opened in Eclipse (or listed in the project navigator) in Windows explore, while it is easy to be achieved in Visual Studio, see below image, you can right click on the file and choose `Open Containing Folder` which will open the containing folder.

Do you know there is an easy way? which is better than navigating to that file directly (cumbersome).
[image]

Comment: 我不懂你的意思. Can you give a detailed exampled of what you want? What do you mean show in Windows explorer?

Comment: I tend to do right click -> properties -> Select the full path, but remove the filename -> Copy -> goto Explorer (e.g. Win+E shortcut) -> Paste

Comment: @Luis Sep, nice Chinese :)

Comment: I typically use the *Easy Shell* plugin.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here it goes, am using Eclipse Juno Service Release 1

[image]

Comment: I don't have that menu option.  You seem to have two "Show In" menu's..?

Comment: @Tom Hunter it's only available in project explorer, you might be using package explorer view.

Comment: Please mention of `Project Explorer` view, Since the option is only available there.

Comment: If you are not coding for Java you should be using `Project Explorer` so I have installed the `StartExplorer` plugin - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9991232/could-anyone-explain-the-exact-difference-among-project-explorer-package-explor

Comment: @Sajan Chandran , Where is the photo ?

Answer (score 5):

*'Show in'* is only available in the *'Package Explorer'* view which comes with the Java perspective. For the more generic *'Project Explorer'* or *'Navigator'* views ([former recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9991232/could-anyone-explain-the-exact-difference-among-project-explorer-package-explor)) you should use  [StartExplorer](http://basti1302.github.io/startexplorer/) plugin instead.

[image: StartExplorer plugin open File Manager link]

With this plugin (as opposed to built in 'Shown in') you can also define a keyboard shortcut through Window --> Preferences --> General --> Keys. The default shortcut for StartExplorer's "Show in File Manager" feature is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>.

Comment: Hi Luis, can you expand on how you "define your own shortcut" in Eclipse?  Thanks