# Aptana: App Explorer vs. Project Explorer

Tags: aptana, aptana3

I was wondering how come Aptana has an extra App Explorer panel to the left of the
usual Project Explorer panel that usually comes with most versions of Eclipse. Why
are two such panels needed in Aptana? What is the exact difference in purpose and
functionality between the two?

Thanks,

John Goche

Answer (score 2):

You should check this: 
[What is the difference between the Eclipse Package Explorer and the Eclipse Project Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265070/what-is-the-difference-between-the-eclipse-package-explorer-and-the-eclipse-proj)

You can do similar things with both panels but App Explorer gives you somethin like closer look at your application and files related to it, and Project Explorer gives you more general view over your App and also file system what can be for example useful while copying files into your projects workspaces.