# What is the simple difference between Project Explorer and Package Explorer in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

In eclipse there are two views. If I view the package explorer then Referenced Libraries folder is there. And if i select the project explorer view than Referenced folder is not there. What is the difference between Project Explorer and Package Explorer.

Comment: http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fref-view-package-explorer.htm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between the Eclipse Package Explorer and the Eclipse Project Explorer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265070/what-is-the-difference-between-the-eclipse-package-explorer-and-the-eclipse-proj)

Answer (score 4):

Package Explorer is the original navigator for basic Java projects. Project Explorer came along later to provide a more extensible view for layered Java technologies, such as Java EE and other languages.

The content is organized a bit differently in the two views, so it will take a bit of getting used to in order to make a transition. Eventually, the Package Explorer view will be phased out.