# eclipse format all project files

Tags: eclipse, format

I know it sounds like a cliche, but I want to know if there is a more convinient way to do that.

What I find now:

- `Package Explore`'s source formatting only formats Java files
- `Project Explore`'s source formatting formats all web files such as JSP and XML

Premraj explains that in [What is the difference between the Eclipse Package Explorer and the Eclipse Project Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52781936/10315163)

- `Project Explorer` additional nodes for web projects, enterprise projects, spring beans and web services.
- `Package Explorer` - provides a view of Java classes for the workspace.

I want to know if there is a way to format all files in one click rather than switch around `Package Explore` and `Project Explore`