# How do I hide jars already in build path Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, ide

I want my `package explorer` or `project explorer` to hide all the jars that I have already added to my build path.

I know two questions address removing all libraries from build path [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218721/how-to-hide-files-from-package-explorer)[[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672990/remove-project-jars-from-project-explorer-view-in-eclipse).

I have all jars showing up twice like this:

[image: Double Jars]

What I want is all imported jars not to show up like this:

[image: Jars Hidden]

Comment: What are the contents of that project's .classpath file? Normally, they wouldn't be shown as files after being added as jars onto the Java Build Path.